# .Net Core @addTagHelper resolve project assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My application is .Net Core I have custom tag helper, the project name is WebUI
I added the following to _ViewImports.cshtml

```
@addTagHelper WebUI.TagHelpers.MenuLinkTagHelper,WebUI
```

I get this error

> Cannot resolve TagHelper containing assembly 'WebUI'. Error: Could not load
>        file or assembly 'WebUI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. 
>       The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was due to the name of the directory was not WebUI. The physical directory should be the same as the project name